# VUE JS Relative Path Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a vuejs simple project and deploy it on my hosting.

first is I build it on production mode using:

```
 npm run build
```

then I have a url which is `www.sample.com/vue-project/` and I put the production version of my vuejs project there. when I visit the link everything behaves okay. When I click on the menu to add blogs it changes the url to this link `www.sample.com/vue-project/add` and it loads the right component. however, when I press `f5` on the page gives `404 error`. don't know why though.
and when I visit this link `https://epm.sg/vue-project/#/add` it gives me the right component. but as you can see on my `Routes Option` I put it on `history mode`.

Here's my code.

**main.js**

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.url.options.root = 'https://sample-proj.firebaseio.com/';

const router = new VueRouter({
  base:'/vue-project/',
  routes:Routes,
  mode: 'history',
});
```

**routes.js**

```
import showBlogs from './components/showBlogs.vue';
import addBlog from './components/addBlog.vue';
import singleBlog from './components/singleBlog.vue';

export default [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: showBlogs
  },
  {
    path: "/add",
    component: addBlog
  },
  {
    path: "/blog/:id",
    component: singleBlog
  }
];
```

**navbar.vue**

```
<template>
  <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><router-link to="/" exact>Blog</router-link></li>
        <li><router-link to="/add" exact>Add New Blog</router-link></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</template>
<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the server you deploy the bundle (js/html/css files) to?

Comment: @acdcjunior linux server sir.. I actually solved the problem using htaccess.. it's okay now/. thank you for your reply,

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would say.

Comment: Everything you need is here ~ https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Hi @Phil thanks for this... very informative.